# Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{1+n}}$ and let $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}a_k$, where $n\in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{1+n}}$ and let $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}a_k$, where $n\in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N$. The Which one of the following is **TRUE**?

(A) Both $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N} a_n$ and $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}c_n$ are convergent

(B) $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N} a_n$ convergent $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}c_n$ is not convergent

(C) $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N} a_n$ is not convergent $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}c_n$ is  convergent

(D) Both $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N} a_n$ and $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}c_n$ are not  convergent

**My Try:-**

$\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N} a_n$  is convergent by Leibniz Alternate theorem. That is Either $(A)$ or $(B)$ is true.

For the convergence of $\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}c_n$

Consider

$$\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}c_n=\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{\sqrt{1+n-k}}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{1+n}}=\sum_{n \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb N}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{-k}}{\sqrt{1+n-k}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n}}$$

How do I proceed further?

Based on the comment, I referred  the wikipedia. still I have doubt on Inequality $|c_n|\geq\1$ How does it come? I am pposting the image of my rough work here.[image]

Comment: This is given as an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens'_theorem) in the Wikipedia article on the *Cauchy product*.

Comment: @JohnDon Sir, I have posted my rough work above. For proving $|c_n|\geq 1$ which inequality should I use?